# File Manager instantly closes when opened

Tags: raspbian

I am running Raspbian on my Pi 2 and am currently remoted in using VNC Viewer - for some reason, whenever I try to use File Manager (through the Taskbar or otherwise) the window will open, then auto close, and the desktop will flicker momentarily. I'm not sure what's going on, as Wolframalpha, Terminal and the Browser icons all work. Is there a way I can check what's causing this issue?

**Update:** After running `pcmanfm` in the terminal,  it appears I'm getting a segmentation fault - there are no other errors simply the following:

`pi@mediaserver:~ $ pcmanfm
** Message: 09:18:54.081: x-terminal-emulator has very limited support, consider choose another terminal
Segmentation fault`

which makes it kind of hard to pin down the solution

Comment: To diagnose the problem you can open a terminal window and start the file manager using the command `pcmanfm`. Have a look at any (error) messages. Add any updates to your question using blockquote (icon with curly brackets)

Comment: @Dirk done! it looks like there's a segmentation fault - not sure what could be causing it though...

Comment: Long time after original question it looks like I had the same issue. I started `pcmanfm ./` from a terminal window that was on my home folder. Then pcmanfm started normall and I was able to start it again from the taskbar shortcut.

Comment: I had removed it from some GUI tool, I forget which.  I don't use it (use mc) but it can hide the automounted volumes on the desktop which are orphaned.  Starting with pcmanfm ./ let me get in there and fix it.

Answer (score 22):

Reinstalling `pcmanfm` worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pcmanfm
```

Comment: One year after question was asked, same problem. Reinstalling worked for me as well. How to submit bug report?

Comment: File manager started to close instant, after I've `apt-get upgrade`. The issue was fixed with reinstalling `pcmanfm`.

Comment: Yep, same problem after `apt-get upgrade`. Also confirms that solution in answer works.

Comment: This is by far the most straight to the point platform on the internet. No long stories just straight to the solution! Great work!